# ExecuteSprocAccessor throws an "Cannot create a mapping for type T" error

Tags: wcf

I have written a procedure to get a string as an input and return the list of parameters . I have used the ExecuteSprocAccessor to map the result to a modal which has the properties that are returned by the ExecuteSprocAccessor.

Detailed Exception :

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled  Message=Cannot create
>   a mapping for type CampaignModel. 
>   Source=Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data  StackTrace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.ReflectionRowMapper`1..ctor(IDictionary`2
>   propertyMappings)       at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.MapBuilder`1.MapBuilderContext.Build()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.MapBuilder`1.BuildAllProperties()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseExtensions.CreateSprocAccessor[TResult](Database
>   database, String procedureName, IParameterMapper parameterMapper)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseExtensions.ExecuteSprocAccessor[TResult](Database
>   database, String procedureName, IParameterMapper parameterMapper,
>   Object[] parameterValues)       at
>   SolarWinds.Services.BusinessLayer.Repositories.DataWarehouseCampaignRepository.GetCampignData(String
>   campaignId) in
>   C:\P4\Lokesh.Ravichandru\depot\EnterpriseServices\Main\Services\Src\Lib\SolarWinds.Services.BusinessLayer\Repositories\DataWarehouseCampaignRepository.cs:line
>   28       at Registration.Campaign.Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\P4\Lokesh.Ravichandru\depot\EnterpriseServices\Main\Services\Registration.Campaign.Test\Program.cs:line
>   16       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String[] args)       at
>   System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)       at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)       at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)       at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  InnerException:
>   System.TypeInitializationException       Message=The type initializer
>   for 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.ReflectionRowMapper`1'
>   threw an exception.
>
>   Source=Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
>
>   TypeName=Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.ReflectionRowMapper`1
>   StackTrace:            at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.ReflectionRowMapper`1..ctor(IDictionary`2
>   propertyMappings)       InnerException:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException            Message=Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.1.505.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Source=Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
>   FileName=Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.1.505.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===LOG: User =
>   SWDEV\Lokesh.RavichandruLOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.Unity,
>   Version=2.1.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   (Fully-specified)LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/P4/Lokesh.Ravichandru/depot/EnterpriseServices/Main/Services/Registration.Campaign.Test/bin/Debug/LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = NULLCalling assembly :
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.505.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.===LOG: This bind
>   starts in default load context.LOG: Using application configuration
>   file:
>   C:\P4\Lokesh.Ravichandru\depot\EnterpriseServices\Main\Services\Registration.Campaign.Test\bin\Debug\Registration.Campaign.Test.vshost.exe.ConfigLOG:
>   Using host configuration file: LOG: Using machine configuration file
>   from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.LOG:
>   Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.1.505.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/P4/Lokesh.Ravichandru/depot/EnterpriseServices/Main/Services/Registration.Campaign.Test/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.DLL.LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/P4/Lokesh.Ravichandru/depot/EnterpriseServices/Main/Services/Registration.Campaign.Test/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Practices.Unity/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.DLL.LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/P4/Lokesh.Ravichandru/depot/EnterpriseServices/Main/Services/Registration.Campaign.Test/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.EXE.LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/P4/Lokesh.Ravichandru/depot/EnterpriseServices/Main/Services/Registration.Campaign.Test/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Practices.Unity/Microsoft.Practices.Unity.EXE.
>               StackTrace:                 at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.ReflectionRowMapper`1..cctor()
>   InnerException:

Adding more details.

I tried by setting the `var resultMapper = MapBuilder<CampaignModel>.MapAllProperties().Build();`

I am getting the exception in the above line.

please can anyone say what is the mistake behind this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to not adding the reference for the following dlls

Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.dll, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration.dll.

in the application that has been using the library.

-Lokesh